# `undefined method `find_asset' for nil:NilClass`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, wicked-pdf

I am using `'rails', '4.2.5'` and `wicked_pdf` gem for generating and downloading PDF, but on Heroku, it's not including css using `wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag` tag.

Heroku error log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'find_asset' for nil:NilClass)
```

Did I miss any configuration here?

Answer (score 51):

To get it work for **development** and **production** environment don't use

```
Rails.application.assets.find_asset(logical_file_path).to_s
```

for *sprockets-rails* version **> 3.0.0** but use this (requires gem *compass-rails*):

```
CompassRails.sprockets.find_asset(logical_file_path).to_s
```

If you don't use gem *compass-rails* you can get the asset with:

```
(Rails.application.assets || ::Sprockets::Railtie.build_environment(Rails.application)).find_asset(logical_file_path).to_s
```

Comment: If you use the statements above to check if an asset exists, remove the little to_s in the end because ``nil.to_s = "" = true``

Answer (score 6):

A simple Google search, revealed that this error [was reported in the official wicked_pdf repo](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/476) in December.

Setting `assets.compile = true` as recommended in the issue would fix it. This change should not be necessary with [`sprocket-rails` != 3.0.0](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/311)

Comment: Have you made the changes and restarted the app?

Comment: Set that where?

Comment: This is never recommended for production!  It's a terrible solution and should only be a last resort. Re-emphasized here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation