# Rails 5 unable to deploy on Heroku due to ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am unable to load a Rails 5 app on Heroku due to the following as per Heroku

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined methodfind_asset' for nil:NilClass)
```

I am using a theme called [Inspinia](http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.5/package.html)

I believe I have located the code that is causing the issue, the theme precompiles the assets and when in production heroku is having issues and produces errors. I can't find any clear solution to this issue, heroku won't be able to assist me any further and suggested Stack and not sure there is another way to get the desired effects on the app. I tried remove the find_assets method and it works locally, but causes an H10 error on heroku.

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Get Leased Up!</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Include style per-controller - vendor plugins -->
    <!-- this is where the error comes from --> 
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] if ::Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{params[:controller]}.css") %>

    <!-- Main css styles -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

    <!-- Main javascript files -->
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>


  </head>
  <body>
...
</body>
```

assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w{ ... }
```

heroku message and logs

```
Thanks for reaching out. A 200 status response indicates the request has succeeded, so the log you shared isn't the error. That said, I went ahead and monitored your app while loading the root page and found the following:

2017-08-10T17:27:02.482836+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-10T17:27:02.482635 #4]  INFO -- : [3c945419-e22f-428f-9212-bebdad98f929] Started GET "/" for 71.198.136.218 at 2017-08-10 17:27:02 +0000
2017-08-10T17:27:02.533224+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-10T17:27:02.533084 #4]  INFO -- : [3c945419-e22f-428f-9212-bebdad98f929] Processing by LandingController#index as HTML
2017-08-10T17:27:02.596368+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-10T17:27:02.596232 #4]  INFO -- : [3c945419-e22f-428f-9212-bebdad98f929]   Rendering landing/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-08-10T17:27:02.645104+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-10T17:27:02.644968 #4]  INFO -- : [3c945419-e22f-428f-9212-bebdad98f929]   Rendered landing/index.html.erb within layouts/application (48.5ms)
2017-08-10T17:27:02.675935+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-10T17:27:02.675800 #4]  INFO -- : [3c945419-e22f-428f-9212-bebdad98f929] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 142ms
2017-08-10T17:27:02.677803+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-08-10T17:27:02.677709 #4] FATAL -- : [3c945419-e22f-428f-9212-bebdad98f929]
2017-08-10T17:27:02.677879+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-08-10T17:27:02.677804 #4] FATAL -- : [3c945419-e22f-428f-9212-bebdad98f929] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `find_asset' for nil:NilClass):
The issue is ActionView::Template::Error (undefined methodfind_asset' for nil:NilClass)`, so you will need to fix that in order to resolve the issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same problem with building ruby on rails to Heroku.

If you use the statements above to check if an asset exists, remove the little to_s in the end because nil.to_s = "" = tru

There is the same question like this. For more details, please try it.
[`undefined method `find_asset' for nil:NilClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251759/undefined-method-find-asset-for-nilnilclass)